# Changing an android text view to a list view

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-adapter

I was populating a text view from my content provider by using:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.exercises);

     resultView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);
}
```

and

```
   @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        StringBuilder res=new StringBuilder();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            res.append("\n"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"))+ "-"+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        resultView.setText(res);
```

I want to adjust this to feature each item in a list view. I tried the following:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.exercises, listItems);
        ListView mylist=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.res);


        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            String temp= " : " + i;
            listItems.add(temp);
        }
        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
```

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRetrieve"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickDisplayNames"
        android:text="Display exercises"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/res"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am using dummy data for the last part to try and get it working as an example. For some reason this will not load anything. What is the easiest way to create a list view that displays the information in the text view?

Comment: please post your xml layout also

Comment: and what is this layout.. **R.layout.exercises**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting your adapter before any content is added to the list.

change your code into this.

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView mylist=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.res);

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            String temp= " : " + i;
            listItems.add(temp);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.exercises, listItems);
        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
```

The simplest way is by setting your adapter like this.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
```